# What happens if I don't pass a ref to a RN component using forwardRef?

Tags: react-native, react-forwardref

I have a subcomponent using forwardRef to get a ref from the parent component, however, I'm curious as to what happens if I didn't pass in a ref from the parent component. I tested other parent components that are also using this subcomponent, but aren't passing in a ref and they seem to work perfectly fine. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `forwardRef` is implemented is to have access to some functions or state properties of that subcomponent. If you do not pass that ref to it, you simply cannot access those from your parent component; most likely where the ref is not passed, there are not used any functions/state properties of the subcomponent, that's why it works fine. (If you take a look at the time when classes were used instead of functional components, you'd see that the `ref` was a property present to each class by default. However, it is not recommended to use forwardRef (only if it's an overhead to do otherwise), as they also say in the documentation, since it is an anti pattern)